# CommitLogSync exception

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've installed cassandra on 3 RHEL servers. I've configured 2 datacentres. 
The YAML file looks like:

cluster_name: 'Cluster1'

num_tokens: 256

partitioner:                org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:- /home/cass/share/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /home/cass/  share/cassandra/commitlog

saved_caches_directory: /home/cass/share/cassandra/saved_caches

seed_provider:
   - class_name:   org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
parameters:
         - seeds: "172.16.129.140"
listen_address: 'IP address of the node'

endpoint_snitch:     GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

I'm getting the below exception:
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Missing required directive CommitLogSync

Missing required directive CommitLogSync

ERROR 05:55:21 Exception encountered during startup: Missing required directive CommitLogSync

What exactly is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your cassandra.yaml a modified version of the shipped one? Even default values need to be in there.

From a quick look of your snippets - does the commitlog directory really exist?

`commitlog_directory: /home/cass/ share/cassandra/commitlog`

There is a space in there and maybe it is just a simple typo. From the docs:

> commitlog_sync
>
> (Default: periodic) The method that Cassandra uses to
>   acknowledge writes in milliseconds:
>
> periodic: (Default: 10000
>   milliseconds [10 seconds]) With commitlog_sync_period_in_ms, controls
>   how often the commit log is synchronized to disk. Periodic syncs are
>   acknowledged immediately.
>
> batch: (Default: disabled)note With commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms
>   (Default: 2 ms), controls how long Cassandra waits for other writes
>   before performing a sync. When this method is enabled, Cassandra does
>   not acknowledge writes until they are fsynced to disk.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html

To be safe to have default values and all parameters set I always recommend to use the shipped cassandra.yaml and only modify the settings that need other values. This also makes it easier while upgrading - diff is your friend - not to miss new parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I installed cassandra 4.1.0 using the binary terball. In my case after setting `commitlog_directory` I still got  the error. The minimal configuration that I ended op setting to make it work is the following:

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
        - seeds: "192.168.56.101"
data_file_directories:
  - /install_location/data/data
listen_address: 192.168.56.101
commitlog_directory: /install_location/data/commit_log
saved_caches_directory: /install_location/saved_caches
cdc_raw_directory: /install_location/data/cdc_raw
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period: 10000ms
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval: 100ms
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval: 600000ms
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 1.0
```

On debian 9. Also make sure all the directories are in the file tree.

For een example how the file tree should look like see the [cassandra installation documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-binary-tarball).